# May I Use Graphics From Proprietary Games in FOSS?

Tags: copyright, assets

May I use images made from NES game screenshots (Mario, Pac-Man) in an Open Source Project?

E.g. these are for *"Error happened"* events:
[image: Mario jumps on a hedge]
[image: Pacman eats mushroom]

Notes:

1. Pac-Man seems to be not from a game screenshot, but a reproduction (couldn't find the source).
2. I'm not sure about whole screenshots too — may I, in example, use screenshot of [Pac-Man bug](https://images.google.com/?q=pacman%20error) as a page background? As an accompanying picture on the page/blog post?

Comment: Not knowing some facts is not a reason for downvote, especially when author tried searching an answer and his question is well formed. Thanks for you answer though.

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems to be a decently fair question. It's a bit of a legal question, but I'm not worried about that.

Comment: What possible reason do you think you would be legally allowed to use someone else's copyrighted assets without permission??

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't use assets verbatim, I change them, so it is a derivative work and it's not always clear when derivative becomes a separate asset of its own. Also screenshot is like a photo and I'm not sure if every photo belongs to those whose assets are depicted on it.

Comment: Under no circumstance you can use somebody's copyright works without permission. Whether your project is open source or not don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your work pretends to be collage:

> Remixes will inevitably encounter legal problems when the whole or a
>   substantial part of the original material has been reproduced, copied,
>   communicated, adapted or performed – unless a permission has been
>   given in advance through a voluntary open content license like a
>   Creative Commons license, ...
>   Generally, the courts consider what will amount to a substantial part
>   by reference to its quality, as opposed to quantity and the importance
>   the part taken bears in relation to the work as whole.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remix#Copyright_implications

Does this quote concerns using whole screenshots too (see question)?